# Hadoop File Splits : CompositeInputFormat : Inner Join

Tags: hadoop, split, mapreduce

I am using CompositeInputFormat to provide input to a hadoop job.

The number of splits generated is the total number of files given as input to CompositeInputFormat ( for joining ).

The job is completely ignoring the block size and max split size ( while taking input from CompositeInputFormat). This is resulting into long running Map Tasks and is making system slow as the input files are larger than the block size.

Is anyone aware of any way through which the number of splits can be managed for CompositeInputFormat?

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, CompositeInputFormat has to ignore the block/split size. In CompositeInputFormat, the input files need to be sorted and partitioned identically... therefore, Hadoop has no way to determine where to split the file to maintain this property. It has no way to determine where to split the file to keep the files organized.

The only way to get around this is to split and partition the files manually into smaller splits. You can do this by passing the data through a mapreduce job (probably just identity mapper and identity reducer) with a larger amount of reducers. Just be sure to pass both of your data sets through with the same number of reducers.

Comment: I am already using the maximum numbers of reducers. I need smaller block size for multiple map waves. Right now the map tasks are too big, which is creating performance problems, as well as task failures at times.

Comment: I don't think you are understanding what I am saying. The problem is you can't split up the map tasks by input splits when using CompositeInputFormat. A way around this is the manually split up the files yourself. So, take your big files and split them into smaller files. One way to do this is what I suggest in my 2nd paragraph. There is no such thing as the maximum number of reducers, by the way.

Comment: My input is output of a different mapreduce job. The number of output files by a mapreduce job is equal to the number of reducer tasks used. The maximum number of redcuer tasks is equal to the reducer task capacity of the cluster. In this scenario, running one mapreduce job, then splitting file, and then run another mapreduce job does not fit as the solution.

Comment: Wrong-- the maximum number of reducers is not the capacity of the cluster-- try upping it.

Comment: @DonaldMiner: Excellent!!! The CompositeInputFormat was driving me crazy! Your post clarified everything to me! I saw that you wrote a book! My next acquisition!

Comment: @Rubber MapReduce Design Patterns has a section on composite input format in the joins chapter.

Comment: @DonaldMiner: I didnt understand the requirement, that the output files must be not splittable. It it saying that, the output of identity map-reduce, must be not splittable. For example,  part-r000X, must be smaller then 64 mb (the HDFS block size)? So do i need to make my identity map-reduce handle this requirement? Am I right?