# Using CompositeInputFormat

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, apache-pig

I'm trying to implement a map-side join through the hadoop, using CompositeInputFormat class. For this I need to meet the following criteria:

> The inputs are to each map must be partitioned and sorted in a
>   specific way. Each input dataset must be divided into the same number
>   of partitions, and it must be sorted by the same key (the join key) in
>   each source. All the records for the private key must reside in the
>   same partition and Which is mandatory.

I need to create a mapreduce  job and execute it, only to meet this requirement? Do I need to create an "Identity Mapper and Reducer" to do this? Or is there any other way using HIVE or PIG?

Thanks

Comment: I found the answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8654200/hadoop-file-splits-compositeinputformat-inner-join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Identity Mapper/Reducer would suffice assuming you set the number of reducers same for pre-processing of both the inputs. as by default it will use HashPartiioner and WritableComparator to sort and process the input.

Answer (score 1):

Identity Mapper/Reducer would work only if you already have the join key as the key in both the files.

If not, you need to write a simple map to make the join key as the key for the output and pass it through an Identity Reducer.